# How can i make data submitted by user to be into a new Firebase key, key only created when Submit button is clicked to pass the data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to make a form fill by user, and once user click 'Submit' button, data will be stored in a new key in Firebase. The new key only exists once the 'Submit' button is clicked to pass the data to Firebase.

This is my current codes:

CustomersDetail.java

```
public class CustomersDetail extends AppCompatActivity {

    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference customerDetails;

    TextView editPhone, editName, editDOB, editEmail;

    Button btnSubmit;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_customers_detail);

        //Firebase
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        customerDetails = database.getReference("Customer Details");

        btnSubmit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);


        btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //Click 'Submit'
                //Submit to Firebase
                //Create new Request
                CustomerDetail custDetail = new CustomerDetail(
                        editPhone.getText().toString(),
                        editName.getText().toString(),
                        editDOB.getText().toString(),
                        editEmail.getText().toString()
                );

                //Submit to Firebase
                customerDetails.child(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                        .setValue(custDetail);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

activity_customers_detail.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText
            android:id="@+id/editPhone"
            android:hint="Phone Number"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColorHint="@android:color/black"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:inputType="phone"
            app:met_baseColor="@android:color/black"
            app:met_floatingLabel="highlight"
            app:met_maxCharacters="15"
            app:met_primaryColor="@android:color/black"
            app:met_singleLineEllipsis="true"
            />

        <com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText
            android:id="@+id/editName"
            android:hint="Full Name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColorHint="@android:color/black"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:inputType="text"
            app:met_baseColor="@android:color/black"
            app:met_floatingLabel="highlight"
            app:met_maxCharacters="50"
            app:met_primaryColor="@android:color/black"
            app:met_singleLineEllipsis="true"
            />

        <com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText
            android:id="@+id/editDOB"
            android:hint="Date of Birth (DD/MM/YYYY)"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColorHint="@android:color/black"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:inputType="date"
            app:met_baseColor="@android:color/black"
            app:met_floatingLabel="highlight"
            app:met_maxCharacters="30"
            app:met_primaryColor="@android:color/black"
            app:met_singleLineEllipsis="true"
            />

        <com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText
            android:id="@+id/editEmail"
            android:hint="Email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColorHint="@android:color/black"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            app:met_baseColor="@android:color/black"
            app:met_floatingLabel="highlight"
            app:met_maxCharacters="30"
            app:met_primaryColor="@android:color/black"
            app:met_singleLineEllipsis="true"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
        android:id="@+id/btnSubmit"
        android:text="Submit"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        app:buttonColor="@color/button"
        app:cornerRadius="4dp"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You have to use push datasnapshot method when you create your firebaseDatabaseListener, but seems like you did not got to that part yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am bit confused as if you are using TextView or EdiTtext?

Whatever you are using, you need to link that with something in your xml file.

Place this code inside the onClick() method, or create a additional method, call that method within onClick() of a button and you can write the defination of the  method outside.

The code to submit data to Firebase can be done by:

```
customerDetails.child(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                    .setValue(custDetail);

//TO READ DATA

customerDetails.child(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            CustomerDetail cd = dataSnapshot.getValue(CustomerDetail.class);
}
 @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            Log.d(TAG, "Failed To Read data", databaseError.toException());

        }
    });
```